# How to find confidence interval for correlation?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, sample

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables from two correlated binomial distribution with different probability parameters and correlation $\rho$. Suppose we have samples for $X$ and $Y$. How should we find the confidence interval for the sample correlation?

I learned that if $X$ and $Y$ are from bivariate normals, then the Fisher transformed correlation is subject to a normal distribution with variance $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N-3}}$.

Comment: How large are your samples?  This is important for considerations of bootstrapping and asymptotics both.

Comment: Not very large. Say $X$ and $Y$ are default rates within a year for investment grade and non-investment grade companies, respectively. The data ranges from 1970 to 2017.

Comment: Given that they are rates, if the number of observations making up $X$ and $Y$ is reasonably large, $X$ and $Y$ may well be easily treated as continuous.  I'd still avoid making the Normal assumption, as the various recessions would induce a lot of positive skew in the two variables, or so it seems to me.  If you want to deal with the count data, then the parameters of each year's binomial distributions will change from year to year, greatly complicating your analysis.

Comment: Thanks. For now I will use bootstrap unless something better comes up.